# Images.xcassets add iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus images

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6.1, xcasset

I need to use background image for next screen sizes:

- **960 x 640**
- **1136 x 640**
- **1334 x 750**
- **2208 x 1242**

In Main storyboard I just use one file name and I like it, because I can set all images in assets for just one item. How can I set my Images.xcassets to support all screen sizes above?

I can't find how to set **1136 x 640** and **1334 x 750** image here:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

on the right side of xcode you can add device support like in this snapshot
and it will show you all the orientation which you needed

> 1-For iPhone 4 s
>
> 640 x 960 (@2x)
>
> 2-For iPhone 5,5s,5c
>
> 640 x 1136 (@2x)
>
> 3-For iPhone 6:
>
> 750 x 1334 (@2x) for portrait
> 1334 x 750 (@2x) for landscape
>
> 4-For iPhone 6 Plus:
>
> 1242 x 2208 (@3x) for portrait
> 2208 x 1242 (@3x) for landscape

Just put the high resolution image in the 2x blank image it will automatically use this image for iphone 5

and you can follow this link too
http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/launchImages.html

Comment: yes but it is app icons, but I need to use background for my views

Comment: I've found this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26020979/xcode-6-xcassets-for-universal-image-support) but they also don't know how to use iPhone 6 image

Comment: just drag the three sizes into these blank images 960 x 640 for 1x(iphone4s) , 1334 x 750 for 2x (iphone5,5s,6) and 2208 x 1242 for 3x iphone 6+ Just drag the images