# Retina 4 2x is never used for iPhone 5 simulator in Xcode 6.2 image asset

Tags: image, screen-resolution, xcode-6.2, ios8.2

I'm using Device Specific in one of my image sets (image0) and having 3 images for 2x, Retina 4 2x and 3x.

iPhone 6 Plus simulator uses the 3x and iPhone 4/4s uses the 2x.

The problem is that iPhone 5/5s simulator never uses the Retina 4 2x (green one in the screen shot below)

These are the resolutions:
2x: 640 x 960
Retina 4 2x: 640 x 1136
3x: 1242 x 2208

[image]

**EDIT1**

I tried as per the suggestion below to set the image in IB but it still selects the 2x version!

[image]

Comment: Did Retina 2x disappear for Xcode 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your project's deployment target is set to 6.0. Retina 4 images won't be used on iPhone 5 for iOS pre 7.0.

Change the deployment target to 7.0 or above and the correct image will be used when you run in the simulator (even if not reflected in IB).

[image: deployment target]

[image: simulator]

Comment: Thank you but I cannot try it now cuz I'm away from my Mac. Your screen shot proves it works and thus I accepted the answer.