# how i can solve Image auto resize in iphone 4 5 6 6+

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I give three types of image like

```
image.png
image@2x.png
image@3x.png
```

but not working image autoresize in all device.

Comment: In what code do you use the images?

Comment: i have check device size like

Comment: CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

Comment: You shouldn't need to check the devoices size. What code do you use the images in? Where is `[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]`?

Comment: yes this one [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]

Comment: Can you give a larger portion of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

understand the `autoresize` concept , the following image is the description that how to we use the `autoresizing` on `Left, right , top and bottom`.

So, I used to think according to this snapshot:
[image]

**Scenario 1**:
 `(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)` // it automatically set the width, height, left and bottom:

[image: (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)]

**Scenario 2**:
 `(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin)` // it is changed into only width and height:

[image: (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin)]

- **1x** images are for the original iPhone through the 3GS - 'standard' resolution devices (3.5" screens)
- **2x** images are for the iPhone 4, 4S (3.5" Retina screens) and also iPhone 6.
- **Retina 4 2x** are for the iPhone 5 and 5s (4" Retina screens)
- **3x** images are for the new iPhone 6+ (5.5" super-Retina [3x] screen)

Answer (score 0):

Usually UIImage displays in UIImageView, so in order to keep the same size for all devices you can set contentMode property of UIImageView

Choose one of this options for your purpose

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIViewContentMode) {
UIViewContentModeScaleToFill,
UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit,      // contents scaled to fit with fixed aspect. remainder is transparent
UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill,     // contents scaled to fill with fixed aspect. some portion of content may be clipped.
UIViewContentModeRedraw,              // redraw on bounds change (calls -setNeedsDisplay)
UIViewContentModeCenter,              // contents remain same size. positioned adjusted.
UIViewContentModeTop,
UIViewContentModeBottom,
UIViewContentModeLeft,
UIViewContentModeRight,
UIViewContentModeTopLeft,
UIViewContentModeTopRight,
UIViewContentModeBottomLeft,
UIViewContentModeBottomRight,
};
```

if you really want to keep real size of image with const value, use :

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    // In next line, pass 0.0 to use the current device's pixel scaling factor (and thus account for Retina resolution).
    // Pass 1.0 to force exact pixel size.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

as answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/2658801/2382237

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26020979/xcode-6-xcassets-for-universal-image-support), will provide some information

It says about 2x 3x images using image xcassets.