# Why is the image so small?

Tags: ios, swift, image-size

I have @1x, @2x, and @3x image, but when I change the image of the button, the image does not fill the size of the button, instead it's really small. Why is this happening? How do I fix it? Any help is appreciated.

```
self.reg.setImage(UIImage(named: "regButton.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    self.in.setImage(UIImage(named: "inStart.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Answer (score 1):

try the button property as like

```
button.contentMode = .ScaleToFill
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .Fill
button.contentVerticalAlignment = .Fill
```

else try

```
self.reg.setImage(UIImage(named: "regButton"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

inthis place use

```
self.reg.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "regButton"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

else another option

```
self.reg.imageView().contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
self.reg.setImage(UIImage(named: "regButton"), forState: .Normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using imageassets. No need to use the image extention. Simple add the image name. At run time as per the device it will pick the image as per the device resolution.

**Edited code:**

```
self.reg.setImage(UIImage(named: "regButton"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

self.in.setImage(UIImage(named: "inStart"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

For more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26085718/3051458

Comment: It still appears small.

Comment: Can you share screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
self.in.imageView?.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
self.reg.imageView?.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
```