# How to use xcassets/universal background images for different iPhones/iPads?

Tags: ios, xcode

I would like to display a different background for each different device (i.e. iPhone 4S, iPhone 5, iPhone6, iPhone 6Plus etc.). I am not talking about launch images but app's backgrounds that will be displayed while using the app.

I have added the following code in my ViewController:

```
var bgImage     = UIImage(named: "main_bg");
var imageView   = UIImageView(frame: self.view.bounds);
imageView.image = bgImage
self.view.addSubview(imageView)
self.view.sendSubviewToBack(imageView)
```

And I am ready to add the assets into the Images.xcassets catalog.

This is what I see when I create a new "Image set"

[image]

Therefore, I am trying to match the assets with each different device.

Thanks to this question: [universal image support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26191308/4063626) I now know that these devices will access the following images:

> iPhone 3 -> 1x (image size: 320x480px)
>
> iPhone 4/4S/6 -> 2x (image size: 640x960px)
>
> iPhone 5/5c/5s/iPod Touch -> Retina 4 2x (image size: 640x1336)
>
> iPhone 6 Plus -> 3x (image size: 1242 x 2208)

My question is, how can iPhones 4/4s and 6 access the same image if, clearly, it's not in the right size for both devices?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have any 3x images?

Comment: My question is generic, I could have 3x images but as far as I know 3x images are only used from iPhone 6 Plus?

Comment: The 2x and 3x suffix are just pixel density.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check this answer:
[How to handle image scale on all the available iPhone resolutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25970124/4063626)

You can use this code to configure a different image as well:

```
NSNumber *screenWidth = @([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width);
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name-%@w", screenWidth];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```