# How to scale images to different iPhone screen using storyboards?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, image

I am developing an app in which i am displaying certain images such as delete icon,search icon.I have images by names are

- delete.png
- delete@2x.png
- delete@3x.png

  I have created `images.xcassets` & added the images in that for 1x,2x & 3x. Now i have added an `UIImageView` on story board & it's default image is `delete.png(32*32)` it runs fine on 3.5 inch screen but images does not scale on 4.7 & 5.5 inch screen iPhone. Can some one please help me out.What to & how to do it?

Comment: Instead of using `delete.png` with `delete`

Comment: are all 2x and 3x images  with the same Ratio as 1x ??? and check the imageView property is set the scaleToFit

Comment: Is your image view resize properly?

Comment: @FattiKhan all images of diffrent size

Comment: i have used scale to fill property but it does not work?@FattiKhan

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle image scale on all the available iPhone resolutions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969533/how-to-handle-image-scale-on-all-the-available-iphone-resolutions)

Comment: as a ratio set the images with the exact size as example if the 1x image is 30 px then 2x must be 60px and 3x 90px

Answer (score 1):

I thick @Banning and @Fatti Khan suggestion will be the solution of the problem.
Instead of using image name as delete.png use just delete 
as a ratio set the images with the exact size as example if the 1x image is 30 px then 2x must be 60px and 3x 90px

```
1x images are for the original iPhone through the 3GS - 'standard' resolution devices (3.5" screens)

2x images are for the iPhone 4, 4S (3.5" Retina screens) and also iPhone 6.

Retina 4 2x are for the iPhone 5 and 5s (4" Retina screens)

3x images are for the new iPhone 6+ (5.5" super-Retina [3x] screen)
```

[image]

EDIT:
please clean your project and then check again (cmd+shift+k) of delete your derived data.
also check your view is autolayout enable or disable.

or

add The launch image Default-568h@2x.png as i thought your Code unable to detect the different type of screens it have,so follow this steps

1. First I would like to suggest that,
2. Preapre all Images,
3. Select Project from Project Navigator And Go to Summary and scroll down this
   screen appears, then right click on that and choose file from your
   computer it will automatically copied to project and it will entered
   in plist file also..
4. if your application is universal then you have
   to set for iPhone and iPad Both.
   [image]

Comment: please check the Edit answer and try it,is it working?

Comment: I am using xcode 6.I don't have any option of summary.I have copied all images to a group in xcode then i have drag & drop the images to images.xcassets.

Comment: just check whether your code able to check the screensize with different screens  or not ? check using screenbound condition.